# Set user's secret key in Django Rest Framework JWT

Tags: django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-auth, django-rest-framework-jwt

I am using [Django REST framework JWT](https://jpadilla.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/)
 for authentication in my Django Rest API.

I want to use user-password as the user's secret key so that tokens become unusable when the user changes the password. According to [this documentation](https://jpadilla.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/), I have to set the value of JWT_GET_USER_SECRET_KEY for it and value should be a function, accepting user as the only parameter and returning its secret key. The documentation doesn't have an example of such a function.

Should I just write a function that takes a user instance and return the password?
Can someone give an example of how this function should be written?

Comment: Why you would do that? You can simply revoke all tokens of user whenever he/she change his/her password! But more importantly: have you tested if old tokens are usable when user have changed password?

Comment: I have tested and found that old tokens are still usable because tokens are generated based on the secret key of my web application which doesn't change. After changing the password I can remove tokens from the client browser. But that will only happen if my web app is open in the browser. Otherwise, tokens won't be removed and the user will be able to continue using them later. If I can make those tokens unusable, they will be removed automatically next time when the user opens the web app.